# Active Record Pattern and Constraints

Tags: design-patterns, activerecord

When implementing the active record pattern should I implement the MS SQL Server `CHECK` constraints and the MySQL `ENUM` and `SET` constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those are rather easy to implement constraints (compared to data integrity constraints) and I do not see why not!

Comment: I am not allowed to that yet as I am still below the reputation of 15. Thanks for the reminder though.

Comment: there you go, you have only 3 more to go ;)